# Capitalizing letters on a Masked text box

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

In my XAML I have a masked text box with this mask:

```
 Mask="##:## aa"
```

so user can enter a time like "12:45 am" .
I was wondering if there is a way to modify the mask such that even if user types "am" it automatically converts it to "AM"? 
Or there is no way and I should handle the conversion on a lost focus event of the text box?

Answer (score 2):

In a Gross mode you could do this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
OnLostFocusEvent
{
textbox.text.ToUpper();
}
```

It is not the most elegant way to do it, but answer your question.

If you want something more sophisticated you could try one of the solutions presented here as well

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/8c28b5c9-00a2-4b71-a854-ede0a3f10500/implement-mask-edit-textbox-in-silverlight?forum=silverlightcontrols

Hope it helps.